# Including External Python Packages with Python Executable

Tags: python, package, executable

I have made my own Executable from a python script which I want to run on a computer that does not have Python installed on it. My only problem is there are packages I have included which are not default python packages (e.g. pynput). Otherwise, the Executable would run fine without Python installed. Is there a way to include Python packages with my executable? Can I put the packages in the same folder as the script and import them from there? If so, would I then be able to transport them along with my Executable? I have already googled a solution but I cannot find anything on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following method :

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

pyinstaller is a package for generating executable files for python and can be ran from command line or terminal

in the same directory of your pyhton file run following command

```
pyinstaller --onefile nameofyourfile.py
```

after its done if you check your folder there should be a dist folder

inside that you can find an executable to your python file which has no dependencies to other packages

Comment: I know how to make the executable. My question is how do I run it on a computer without certain packages installed. For example, I can not make an executable that imports pynput and run it on a computer without pynput installed.

Comment: there would be no problem, while generating the executable all intentional data is stored in generated file if that make sense... long story short there would be no such problem

Comment: Oh, now I see! Thanks!

Comment: @X-_-FARZA_D-_-X do you know if this is possible with PDM?

Comment: @Hussam I'm not sure what PDMs are or how they behave but if python3 works pyinstaller should technically work